# Android app crashes on button1 click in mobile but it runs successfully in emulator

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-emulator

Its working completely in emulator and i even checked it on bluestack but when i use it in mobile it crashes when i press button1 when it is supposed to load a new layout and for button4 when it checks for internet connectivity it works fine..

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.firstapp;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button button1, button2,button4,check_button1,canda, candb;
private EditText vid,pin;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadmain();

}

//Load Main Layout
public void loadmain()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnbutton1();
    addListenerOnbutton4();
    addListenerOnbutton2();

}

//Load check_voter layout
public void loadcheck_voters()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.check_voters);
    vid = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    pin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    addListenerOncheck_button1();
}

public void loadclist()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.clist);
    addListenerOncanda();
    addListenerOncandb();
}

public void validate()
{
    String vid1 = vid.getText().toString();
      String pin1 = pin.getText().toString();
      new ValidateVoter(this).execute(vid1,pin1);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void addListenerOnbutton1() 
{

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            loadcheck_voters();
        }
    });

}

public void addListenerOnbutton4() 
{

    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            isInternetOn();
        }
    });

}

public void addListenerOnbutton2() 
{

    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {   
            //
        }
    });

}

public void addListenerOncheck_button1() 
{

    check_button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.check_button1);
    check_button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            validate();
            loadclist();
        }
    });

}

public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
    try{
        URL myUrl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        connection.connect();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        return false;
    }
}

public void  addListenerOncanda()
{
    canda = (Button) findViewById(R.id.canda);
    canda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            voteA();
        }
    });
}

public void  addListenerOncandb()
{
    candb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.candb);
    candb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            voteB();
        }
    });
}

public void voteA()
{
    String cand="Candidate A";
    new IncVoteA().execute(cand);
    loadmain();
    Toast.makeText(this, "You Voted for Candidate A", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void voteB()
{
    String cand="Candidate B";
    new IncVoteB().execute(cand);
    loadmain();
    Toast.makeText(this, "You Voted for Candidate B", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}



public final boolean isInternetOn() {


    ConnectivityManager connec =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(getBaseContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String disp=new String();

        if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
             connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
             connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
             connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ) 
        {


            new CheckConn(this).execute();
            return true;

        } 
        else if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||  connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED  ) 
        {

            Toast.makeText(this,"Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
      return false;
}

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat

```
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1884)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2990)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1723)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.loadcheck_voters(MainActivity.java:43)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:79)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4261)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17420)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-22 20:20:54.580: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Stack Trace? These always help to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Also, while I appreciate including lots of code, if `button1` is the error, you should probably post the functions that are called when `button1` is clicked, and enough code to get the context, but not quite the entire file... The Manifest is rarely required...

Comment: instead of speculation about the cause, we should wait for the stacktrace.. That is what a stacktrace is good for

Comment: The red portion of the log cat is what is helpful for this. Also, please post it directly just as you would code, and it looks like you posted the emulator logcat.

Comment: `button1` code is already there shall i post the layout xml file that gets loaded??

Comment: got the logcat & trace for mobile changed it in the above code...its saying `ResourceNotFoundException` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway thanx guys...connected my mobile with eclipse got the stack trace. Checked the `ResourceNotFoundEception` was for which resourse in `R.java` file, the layout which was getting loaded on that button was in some `layout-qwerty` folder while I was looking for it in `layout` folder. Corrected that and its all running in mobile as well..